# PHP/Apache Can't Write To Anything

Tags: php, permissions, centos6

I've been encountering an issue on a client site for the past couple of weeks where they can't upload files to a directory outside of the web root.

After looking in the error logs, it looks like PHP is spitting out errors saying the upload directory is not writable. This directory happens to be outside of the web root but there are no `open_basedir` restrictions on the server.

I have a test script that executes the following code:

```
$path = '/var/www/vhosts/testdir';
$writable = is_writable($path) ? 'is writable' : 'is not writable';

echo "$path $writable";
```

When I run the script from the command line with `php test.php` the directory is writable. However, when I access the page from the browser, it is not writable.

Both the web root directory and `testdir` belong to the same user and group and have `755` permissions set. I've tried setting the owner of both dirs to `apache` to no avail.

When I set the permissions for the upload directory to `777` it works, but obviously I don't want all my files to be readable and executable to everyone.

Distro is CentOS 6.7.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: What particular distro is this ?

Comment: @Iain CentOS 6.7. Sorry for not making that clear, I'll edit my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is almost certainly SELinux. Files & directories outside the 'web root' will be unlikely to have the correct SELinux context e.g. httpd_sys_content_t.

You will have to change the SELinux context on the files/directories that you want to be able to write to.

Comment: Hi Iain, thanks for the reply. Do you have any guides that can show me how to do that?

Comment: There is a site search facility in the top right of the page. There you will find there are lots of guides already available to you.

Comment: The context for _writable_ directories is `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`. The context `httpd_sys_content_t` allows only reading.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Isn't that for C7 and onwards ? Isn't the purpose of the http_unified boolean to make C7 work like C6 ?

Comment: It's been that way since at least 6, maybe even 5.

Comment: My contexts appear to be set to a question mark (`?`) - apparently this means SELinux is disabled. Could this still be a SELinux issue?

Comment: OK I see httpd_unified was switched from default on to default off between C6 and C7.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, any suggestions on how I can diagnose this issue further?

Answer (score 0):

The user or group running the httpd must have write access. PHP inherits this from httpd.